# Does the bijectivity of a continuous linear operator on a dense subspace of a Banach space imply the injectivity on the whole space?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a Banach space and let $T:X\longrightarrow X$ be a continuous linear operator. Suppose that there is a dense subspace $N$ of $X$ such that the restriction $T|_{N}:N\longrightarrow N$ is injective and ${\bf surjective}$, i.e., it is a bijection. Is it true that $T$ is necessarily an injection on the whole $X$ (i.e., is it one-to-one on the whole $X$)?
(And, what is the situation if $X$ is a (separable) Hilbert space?)

I think/feel that the answer is negative, but I am unable to find a counterexample. Does anybody have a counterexample for the question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I  have heard something like this from my advisor if I am not mistaking: There exists a space with a subspace of codimension 1 that is dense in it! If this is true, then the embedding (identity) of this subspace provides a counter-example.

Comment: I am not sure about Banach assumption though.

Comment: How is this a counterexample?  The embedding is of course still invective on a full space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X = \ell^2(\mathbb{Z}^+)$, and $N = c_{00}(\mathbb{Z}^+)$ the subspace of sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms. Let $T = I - S$, where $S(e_1) = 0$ and $S(e_n) = \frac{n}{n-1} e_{n-1}$ for $n > 1$. Then

$$\ker T = \mathbb{C}\cdot \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}e_n \neq \{0\},$$

but $T\lvert_N$ is bijective, for $x \in N$ with $x_n = 0$ for $n > k$, we have

$$(T\lvert_N)^{-1}(x) = \sum_{m = 0}^k S^m(x).$$